# Show data from another table into one form - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, associations

I have created 2 table

**Platforms :**

```
  def change
    create_table :platforms do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
```

**Games :**

```
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :image_url
      t.decimal :price
      t.integer :platform_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :games, :platform_id
  end
```

and then this is my _form.html.erb from games

```
<%= form_for(@game) do |f| %>
  <% if @game.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@game.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this game from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @game.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image_url %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :image_url %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :platform %><br>
    <div>
      <%= collection_select( :invoice, :platform_id, Platform.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => false}) %>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

in case I create new game and I chose PlayStation from select input, when I click submit that will be show field from **Games** table like **title, description, price, image_url** I want to show the name of the platform that I have chosen before like **PlayStation** so I added

```
 <p>
  <strong>Platform:</strong>
  <%= @platform.name %>
 </p>
```

to show.html.erb from games but when I try it, I get error

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

did I miss something?
I have tried a few of solutions here, but still error
thx

Comment: Did you set `@platform` instance variable in your controller?

Comment: What is `@platform`? Also are you sure that `platform_id` isn't `nil` when creating a game? because that `collection_select` is wrong.

Comment: @Pavan previously I've made 3 data platform. ie PC, PlayStation and Xbox. What I was wrong to write collection_select?

Comment: Check the values of `platform_id` in `games` table and tell me.

Comment: @pavan btw I think I've solved it :D I've changed `collection_select` to `<%= collection_select( :game, :platform_id, Platform.all, :id, :name, {:multiple => false}) %>` then I changed `<%= @platform.name %>` to `<%= @game.platform.name %>`  I've tried adding game then I choose the platform and all data can be displayed. I don't know `collection_select` that I make are correct or not, but thanks for giving clue :D

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve it through the belongs_to association from the @game variable.

```
<p>
  <strong>Platform:</strong>
  <%= @game.platform.name %>
</p>
```

Comment: still get undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Is the association being correctly set up. What is the log message when you submit the form.

Comment: Check the strong_parameters aren't blacklisting the platform_id parameter. Also check the game record in the rails console to make sure you have actually saved it correctly. The collection_select looks a little bit suspicious to me

Comment: Show us your controllers/games_controller.rb and models/game.rb please. Probably there's something wrong with them. Can be a wrong relationship between models or a strong_parameters badly done.